# Single SQL query for counting and data aggregation

Tags: mysql

I have an app where a user can define a campaign, then have one or more emails in that campaign and then send each of these emails to a number of recipients. I'm looking to write an efficient query that will allow me to get the count of sent emails for each email of each campaign.

I've simplified the database structure to the following 3 tables bellow:

```
campaigns
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+

emails
+----+-------------+---------+------+
| id | campaign_id | subject | body |
+----+-------------+---------+------+

sent_emails
+----+-------------+----------+
| id | campaign_id | email_id |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

What I'm looking for is to aggregate the result in the following form:

```
+-------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+
| campaign_id |  campaign_name  | email_1 | email_2 | email_3 |
+-------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+
|           1 | First campaign  |      10 |       8 |       4 |
|           2 | Second campaign |       5 |       0 |       0 |
|           3 | Third campaign  |       3 |       2 |       0 |
+-------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

So what happened here is that:

- First campaign has 3 emails defined and the sent emails count for each of them is 10, 8 and 4.
- Second campaign has 1 email defined and the sent emails count is 5
- Third campaign has 2 emails defined and the sent emails count is 3 and 2.

I managed to implement it by doing two queries, one for fetching all emails for each campaign and then based on the results a new query to fetch the sent emails count for each email.

Is it possible to do this in a single query? If yes, then how?

Thanks.

Comment: Include the queries you have so far and some sample data that corresponds to your expected results; what you are after *sounds* like simple conditional aggregation. Is 3 emails the maximum per campaign? Or can there be 10, 20...?

Comment: The expected result is depicted in the forth table. There's no maximum number of emails per campaign. It can range from 1 to any number.

Comment: It is not possible for a query to a dynamic number of columns. You would need to do two queries as you described. One to get the meta data, then a generated query to produce the example table you provided.